Using Microsoft.Web.WebView2 in Powershell
I'm trying to make a simple PowerShell script to interact with a website using Microsoft.Web.WebView2. For debugging purpose I put it on a WinForm with green background.
Add-Type -Path "$($env:APPDATA)\..\Local\Microsoft\TeamsMeetingAddin\1.0.23061.1\x86\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$($env:APPDATA)\..\Local\Microsoft\TeamsMeetingAddin\1.0.23061.1\x86\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll"
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Windows.Forms"

$Form = [System.Windows.Forms.Form]::new()
$Form.Width = 1280
$Form.Height = 1024
$Form.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Green

$WebView2 = [Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2]::new()
$WebView2.Width = 1240
$WebView2.Height = 984

$WebView2.CreationProperties = [Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.CoreWebView2CreationProperties]::new()
$WebView2.CreationProperties.UserDataFolder = "C:\1\Temp"
$WebView2.Source = "https://www.google.com"
$WebView2.Update()
$Form.Controls.Add($WebView2)
$Form.ShowDialog()

Unfortunately it just shows a blank green form.
